# How to align the navbar in the center of container in boostrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the navbar to be in the center of the page. How can I give styling to get it in the center. Currently it's starting from the left side of the page.

```
section class="navbarSection">
      <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
             <div class="navBar2">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white paddingo">
        
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item  ">
                      <a class="nav-link firstLink" href="#">WHO WE ARE <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                      <a class="nav-link " href="#">OUR SERVICES</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link " href="#">OUR PROJECTS</a>
                    </li>
                  
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
                    </li>
                  
                   <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">CAREERS</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
    
             </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove ml-auto from navbar-nav:

```
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item  ">
              <a class="nav-link firstLink" href="#">WHO WE ARE <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">OUR SERVICES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">OUR PROJECTS</a>
            </li>
          
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
          
           <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">CAREERS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

And make it **m-auto**, this way the auto margin is applied to both left and right sides.

[Centered bootstrap nav codepen](https://codepen.io/LancelotPierreBlaine/pen/NWpXXKe?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<div class="d-flex col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-primary justify-content-center">
```

So in this way you declare a flex box with justify-content-center and they should get in the right place:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navBar2{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>
    <section class="navbarSection">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="navBar2">
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white paddingo">

                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                    <li class="nav-item  ">
                                        <a class="nav-link firstLink" href="#">WHO WE ARE <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item ">
                                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">OUR SERVICES</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">OUR PROJECTS</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CAREERS</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How to add spaces between the menu items?

Comment: Give padding in nav-item `.nav-item{ padding:32px}`

Comment: Hi, It's perfectly fine but it show padding in mobile as well. Any idea how not remove in mobile responsivness?